# ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. \maketitle

Tags: errors, memory

I have seen many threads about this error, but none seems to help with my particular issue.

This is my code, which including suggestions for the required packages, I intend for it to be the minimum code which yields the problem:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{lineno}

\title{Teachings on Pythagoras}
\author{Guillermo F. Sanchez M.}

\begin{document}
  \setpagewiselinenumbers
  \modulolinenumbers[1]
  \linenumbers
  \frontmatter
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoftables
  \mainmatter
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
Hello.
\end{document}
```

The issue is that, when I comment out "\maketitle", the error persists (even tough the error messages points at it), but if "\tableofcontents" is ALSO commented out, the error goes away.

This is the interpreter I am using:

```
$ pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
  restricted \write18 enabled.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The example code is rather good, but also the document class and a minimal set of packages needed to reproduce the problem should be added.

Comment: Sorry, but the example integrated with the code you suggested doesn't produce errors.

Comment: Rutinary advice: remove aux files and try again. Probably wont work this time but anyway.

Comment: @JLDiaz: I tried deleting the AUX file. It did not work.

Comment: The LOG file: ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\lastLN #1->\ifnum #1
                     <\c@linenumber \let \firstLN \@gobble \fi 
l.37   \maketitle
                 
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

Comment: Works when I remove the \frontmatter, \mainmatter and the \backmatter commands.

Comment: Without an example that reproduces the problem it is going to be very difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: If you don't know what is a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) example, please use the link.

Comment: I tested this on Mac OS X, with the same `pdfLatex` version as yours. It gives me error for having no title. I added `\title` and it's working now.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Thanks. I shall update the original post with a MWE.

Comment: Is that actually the *minimal* code required to reproduce the error? If you remove any of the lines or packages, the error goes away?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Your example works fine for me.

Comment: It can help if you add the command `\listfiles` to your preamble. After this at the end of the log-file you will see all loaded packages and versions. Maybe this can help us to find the flaw.

Comment: Without an example which actually reproduces the error, this is 'unclear'.